# How to show one node from particular content type into all other pages?

Tags: 7, views, rules

I have content type and have few fields and I want to display each node from that content type into basic page.

In this i want to choose which node i want to display on which page.  Like i want to show node1 from A content type into Basic Page 1.  and node2 from A into basic page 2.

Any idea?

Comment: *I want to display each node from that content type into basic page.* So, if that  content type will have 50 nodes, you want to show all those in basic page. Can you please be specific in your question, so Answerer can provide the best solution.

Comment: @CodeNext: i want to display one node of that content type into basic page.  Admin will use which node he wants to display on which page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) Module

> A generic entity reference field Four widgets: Two implemented on top
>   of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes), Two autocomplete
>   widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with
>   comma-separated entries in the same text field) Two formatters: A
>   "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the
>   referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.) A "Rendered
>   entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a
>   configurable view mode

Comment: i don't want to link into another page.. i want to display on same page.. can u tell me how to do that?

Comment: You can use View module. Create a block with referecened nodes and show call that block in node template

Comment: Can you please explain this little more

Comment: Add entity refrence or node reference on basic page content type and add refrence of content which you want to display on that basic page.